# Magento 2: this.options.jsonConfig.mappedAttributes is undefined

Tags: magento2, swatches

Configurable products are not changing the pictures while selecting attributes like size or color. 
I really don't know how to fix this problem. It is two days now and I still facing the same issue.

I noticed while I click on the attribute, it's giving me this error on the swatch-renderer.js.

```
this.options.jsonConfig.mappedAttributes is undefined
```

This is the default swatch-renderer of Magento 2.3.3, not a custom one from the theme.

Can you please help me with that? 
PS, I'm on Magento 2.3.3

Thanks!

Comment: How can we check this thing without getting this error. please check swatch-renderer.js file and check why getting mappedAttributes undefined from jsonConfig. Please trace each and every step.

Comment: Let me know this issue only occurred on product detail page and also occurred on listing page??

Comment: How can I do this? And yes, I'm having the same error on both catalog page and product page

Comment: you need to check where to set data in jsonConfig. you have to trace each and every thing in js and block. may be data would be set in json from block

Comment: I didn't edit the file. That is the standard file from magento. Why should I edit the file?

Comment: _getAttributeCodeById: function (attributeId) {
            var attribute = this.options.jsonConfig.mappedAttributes[attributeId];
            return attribute ? attribute.code : attributeId;
        },

here is where is giving me the error

I did alert. The attributeId looks fine, but of course it doesn't print this this.options.jsonConfig.mappedAttributes[attributeId];

Comment: you can override file in your theme and check

Comment: Just noticed another thing. If I change the attribute to "Dropdown" instead ot "Text Swatch", it will show the standard placeorder of magento and it will change the price also. When I use "Text Swatch", it doesn't update the price and it doesn't update the picture and is giving me the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102214/discussion-between-gerardo-siano-and-naresh-rupareliya).

Comment: I have same problem with Magento 2.4. Did you solve it?

Comment: Yes, that was a problem related to the theme. Ask the theme support to fix it